# Where is the Can.List.Sort Plugin documentation?

Tags: canjs

I see a Can.List.Sort plugin on the download page:

[image]

Where is the documentation?  Also, what are the plans for this plugin?  Deprecation in its future?

Comment: ...If there's no documentation and it's not going to be deprecated, I'll work on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an A+ plugin, so there are no docs.  Anything without docs should be considered unsafe to use.  Its API could change at anytime.

Once it is documented, we will treat it like the rest of CanJS. It will be subject to semantic versioning.

Comment: Just for reference, if OP is still interested in experimenting with that plugin: https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/blob/master/map/sort/sort.md, https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/blob/master/map/sort/sort.js